# If security checks during a layover take too long time and I lose the flight, would the airline find me a solution for free?

Tags: air-travel, layovers

Take for example this flight:

[image: swiss flight]

in 45 minutes you have to go through immigration, security checks, and probably you need to go to a different terminal: it's basically guaranteed that you can't catch the connecting flight

If I lose this connecting flight, are airlines required to find a replacement flight to me? (possibly without charge)

Comment: They might put you through priority queue for immigration/security. Maybe also assign you a golf buggy to get you there. I once got assigned a staff member who made me jog through HKG to make my connection.

Comment: Once I had a Thai Airways car take me from their plane to a Cathay plane, directly on the tarmac.  They're not even in the same alliance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's bought as one trip (which seems to be the case), it's their responsibility, so if it seems possible they will do what it takes, whether that's assigning a staff member (with or without a "golf" car) to help you, or giving you instructions on the fastest way. If they fail they might upgrade you to get you on a later plane towards your destination (you'll probably be eligible for compensation, so they have another clear interest in getting you to where you want to be), they might also be allowed to give you a ticket for a train or something (probably not relevant).

If it is two tickets you bought seperately it's your responsibility, so take care if you have to do that.